# How configure springfox to generate swagger which added auth header for all requests in private endpoints?

Tags: java, spring-security, swagger, swagger-2.0, springfox

Spring security configuration

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChainBean(ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity) {
    httpSecurity.authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/v2/api-docs").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/configuration/ui").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/swagger-resources/**").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/configuration/security").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/v2/**").permitAll()

                .anyExchange().authenticated();
    return httpSecurity.build();
}
```

Rest controller

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @PostMapping("myPath")
    public MyResponse newLoansOffers(@RequestBody MyRequest request) {
        return new MyResponse();
    }
}
```

Spring fox configuration:

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    Class[] clazz = {AuthenticationPrincipal.class};

    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()))
            .select()
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}

private ApiKey apiKey() {
    return new ApiKey("xauth", "X-Auth-Token", "header");
}
```

**What is the problem?**

I click on Authorization button:

[image]

And enter valid value

[image]

But when I send `myPath` request from swagger ui - no `X-Auth-Token`header is passed with request. :(

As I understand springfox does not "take" into account spring security config during swagger generation:

1. Is there a way to do that?
2. If no how make swagger generation with added auth header for private endpoints only?